# Example of a finite category without pushouts or pullbacks

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, pullback, pushforward

I'm trying to find an example of a finite category in which there are no pushouts or pullbacks. By finite category, I mean a category with a finite amount of objects and morphisms.

The concepts of pushouts and pullbacks are new to me, but as far a I understand, they are similar to products and coproducts, only with a few more restrictions. So I tried to find a category with no products or coproducts, but I got nowhere. All of the examples of categories that I know (Gps, Top, Rng, Vect...) seem to have both, so I don't know how to get an example.

Could anyone please lend me a hand? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the empty category count?

Comment: You can artifically create such things. For examle the discrete categories on $n$ objects have no nontrivial limits or colimits at all.

Comment: @FShrike Any discrete category has pushouts and pullbacks. Though you are right we can artificially create such categories: just take a category consisting of a span and separately a cospan.

Comment: @S.C. It must include objects and morphisms, but I would have thought of it too if given the chance...

Comment: @MarkKamsma how so? What do you mean by span and cospan?

Comment: @MarkKamsma As all arrows are identities, the only such (co)limits it has are the ones that involve just a single object. I consider that trivial. Though you are right that it still has all pullbacks since the only possible pullback diagram is the trivial one. The op may still take it as an example of a category without products

Comment: @FShrike It would not be enough, but thanks for the example anyways!

Comment: @GreekCorpse Consider the category $A \leftarrow B \to C$ (such a diagram is called a span). Clearly it doesn't have pushouts because we cannot even complete the span to a commuting square. Similar trick, with the arrows inverted, gives a counterexample to a pullback. Putting the two examples together (take the disjoint union) gives what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of producing such examples is to look at some special cases of pullbacks and pushouts that can be better understood - products and coproducts. Constructing a category without products and coproducts (but with initial and terminal objects, to get them as pushouts and pullbacks) is quite easy just looking at sets. Take for example the full subcategory of $\mathrm{Set}$ with objects $\emptyset, \{0\}, \{0, 1\}$.

Note that products and coproducts in a subcategory do not need to coincide with products and coproducts from category itself, but in this case it is easy to check that both $\{0, 1\} \times \{0, 1\}$ and $\{0, 1\} \amalg \{0, 1\}$ must contain $4$ elements, thus do not exist in $\mathcal C$.

Less artificial, but not really finite (however you can just choose some arbitrary finite subcategory if you want) such category is for example a category of connected manifolds (together with empty set). The lack of coproducts is clear, so also the lack of pushouts. Even though products of connected manifolds are perfectly fine connected manifolds, this category do not have pullbacks in general. A simple counterexample can be constructed for instance from maps $f, g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$
$$
f(x) = |x(x-1)| \\ 
g(x) = 0
$$

The resulting pullback has a form $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 \ \ | \ \ f(x) = g(y)\}$, which is clearly not connected.